# Applet in OBJECT tag not working

Tags: java, eclipse, html, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have created dynamic web project in eclipse and below is structure

**Development Environment**

```
**Applet path**  
/projet/Java Resources/src/com/my/package/MyApplet.java

**HTML path**  
/project/WebContent/index.html
```

and OBJECT tag in index.html

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
    type="application/x-java-applet" width="480" height="640">
    <PARAM name="code" value="com.my.package.MyApplet.class">
</OBJECT>
```

**UPDATE 1**

**Deployment environment**

```
**Applet path**
<tomcat root>/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/classes/com/my/package/MyApplet.class 

**HTML path**
<tomcat root>/webapps/MyProject/index.html
```

The result in IE is 'ClassNotFoundException'.

There are numerous references related to this but I couldn't get it work. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes its from development env (eclipse). I am testing it on localhost so can't share the link.  As for `com.my.package.MyApplet.java` will be translated to `com/my/package/MyApplet.class` right?

Comment: @AndrewThompson here are server paths Applet: `<tomcat root>/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/classes/com/my/package/MyApplet.class` and HTML:`<tomcat root>/webapps/MyProject/index.html`. Please see if you can help based on this.  Adding this to question as well. Thanks.

Comment: Well, `com.my.package` are indeed three separate directories if you see in Eclipse Navigator but eclipse Eclipse Project Explorer shows it that way with Dots :)